# The request failed: Google returned a response with code 400 with Pytrends Python Library for Google Trends API

Tags: python, google-trends

I have the following code:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

keywords = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3']

mapping = {}

pytrends = TrendReq()

for keyword in keywords[:3]:

    print(keyword)
    pytrends.build_payload(keyword,timeframe='today 12-m')
    trend_data = pytrends.interest_over_time()
    series = trend_data[keyword[0]]
    print(series)
    plt.plot(series)
    plt.show()
    mapping[keyword] = series
    time.sleep(65)
```

For the first keyword in the keywords array, this will work. However, as soon as the for loop iterates to the next keyword, I get "pytrends.exceptions.ResponseError: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 400".

Initially, I thought this was because of rate limits but I set time.sleep() in the for loop to over 1 minute in between requests. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the first argument to `build_payload` be a list? i.e.: `pytrends.build_payload([keyword],timeframe='today 12-m')` or maybe better depending on what you're really doing — without the loop: `pytrends.build_payload(keywords,timeframe='today 12-m')`

Comment: Tried that: ```pytrends.build_payload(keywords,timeframe='today 12-m')``` to pass in whole array. I'm still seeing the same error code unfortunately

Comment: Passing a list works for me. See answer below for a working example.

Comment: For me, passing a list fails if the list has more than five elements.   So, keywords = ['apple','orange','pear','peach','banana'] works, but keywords = ['apple','orange','pear','peach','banana','kiwi'] does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help. You need to pass a list into `build_paylod()` per [the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytrends/#api-methods). I suspect you want to compare the results in one chart, but if not this should at least get you closer:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

keywords = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3']

pytrends = TrendReq()

pytrends.build_payload(keywords,timeframe='today 12-m')
trend_data = pytrends.interest_over_time()
series = trend_data[keywords]
plt.plot(series)
plt.show()
```

This will give you a graph like:

[image]

Comment: This seems correct. It needs to accept an array, but the array I was passing was simply too large. With a shorter array, it works.